# What does 'a painting fifteen feet long and ten feet deep' mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

There's this description of a painting in Pratchett's Thud:

> “Of course, people tried to copeah it,” said the curator, accepting a cup. “Oh dear, they hwere terrible! **A painting fifteah feet long and ten feet deep** is really quite impossible to copy hwith any kind of accuraceah—”

I don't understand how a painting can be 'ten feet deep'. What does it mean? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming it's a "normal" painting, it's two-dimensional. Since the ***length*** has already been specified, it's contextually obvious ***deep*** refers to the other dimension (from top to bottom) that would more often be expressed as *ten feet **high***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The fact that is from a Pratchett book suggests that might not be a safe assumption.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That makes sense, but I'm wondering if there's a good reason behind choosing 'deep' instead of 'high'. Maybe there's some art lingo I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: Well, it's pretty obvious we're dealing with a non-native speaker here (the OP here, not the cited curator). I must admit the "aspirated **wh**" orthography works as an amusing device in ***hwere, hwith*** (which so far as I know were *never* aspirated by any native Anglophones), but ***fifteah*** certainly foxed me for a moment. I initially assumed it was some kind of OCR error for ***fifteen***, but then I noticed preceding ***copeah***, and realised it was oddball eye-dialect for ***fifty*** (spoken by someone with an unusual speech impediment, perhaps).

Comment: @Azor-Ahai The painting is supposed to be cut with a knife and rolled up at some point. I think that strongly implies the distance between viewing surface and the wall is modest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the words **where** and **when** if spoken *correctleah* by an English person are indeed pronounced **hwere** and **hwen** but in common parlance the utterer is liable to be mocked.

Comment: @Alexey: Pratchett is a very versatile and amusing writer, but I really don't think it's suitable material for *learning* English. There will be many subtleties and "ungrammatical / non-standard" usages, not all of which will be correctly identified and understood even by native speakers. But as regards the *specific* choice between ***high*** and ***deep*** in this exact context, I don't think you're likely to gain any great insights by mulling it over. He might have said *ten feet **from top to bottom*** if he didn't want to get bogged down with that particular word-choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not read Pratchett but the curator's speech might be mocking his "betters".

Comment: @Weather Vane: I'm a (relatively) old native speaker, so of course I know all about aspirated **wh** in words where the *written* form includes **h**. But I'm not aware this pronunciation ever applied to (past tense BE) ***were*** or ***with***, and I don't think these are likely as facetious (or "hypercorrective") usages either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are right - my second comment perhaps applies.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I haven't read "Thud," but my experience with Pratchett made me consider that the painting is very thin, but hung on the wall 90* from what we'd expect, hence making it 10 feet *deep*, but this is all speculation until someone who's read "Thud" comes along.

Comment: @FumbleFingers recently seen note on someone's front door: "Please do not ring the bell ***has*** the parot will frite." There are cases where people aspirate unnecessarily. Possibly out of ignorance but the contrivance of aspirating is often done by those who otherwise habitually "drop their aitches".

Comment: @Weather Vane: That's just "facetious orthography". And if you ask me, Dickens started the whole idea of "hypercorrected" aspirated **wh** as a literary device evoking uneducated / servile Cockney speech. It certainly doesn't occur in actual speech today except as a facetious usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hwerry well said.

Comment: Interested readers can view the quoted language in greater context [here](http://www.read33.com/thud?page=0,131).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Terry Pratchett makes lots of subtle jokes.

I believe this is one of them.

The painting was done by dwarfs, who live underground. So their paintings, rather than being "high", are "deep".

And of course the curator knows this, and is using the correct terminology.

Comment: The painter was a human who thought he's a chicken. The painting depicts trolls and dwarfs fighting each other, though.

Comment: @Alexey: I don't know whether the joke still works, then. But I don't know what else to make of it. Maybe it was painted by dwarfs in an earlier draft, and Pratchett forgot to edit the joke out.